# SwiftライブラリPageMenu使用時、self.navigationController?.pushViewControllerによる画面遷移ができない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode6, ios8

Xcode6.4、Swiftでiosアプリ開発中です。

Swift製のライブラリ[「PageMenu」](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu)を使用しているのですが、
PageMenuを使用しているFirstView → PegeMenuを使用していないNextView
への遷移ができません。

FirstViewにUIButtonを設置しており、タップアクション時に
`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(NextView(), animated: true)`
で、遷移させたいのですがボタンをタップしても何も起こりません。

```
var modalView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NextView())
modalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
self.presentViewController(modalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

とした時は、モーダルで遷移できます。が、モーダルの場合はNextViewで
`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`
でモーダルを閉じた際に、FirstViewに設置してあるPegeMenuのタブバーがNavigationBarの後ろに隠れてしまいます。（正常時はNavigationBarの下にPageMenuのタブがあります）

何か解決策はありますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

モーダル遷移の際は

```
var modalView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NextView()) 
modalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical 
self.view.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(modalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

とすることで、NextViewから戻ってきた際もレイアウト崩れをしなくなりました。

NavigationContorollerを使った遷移の方は未解決です。